# Bad connector on HP laptop screen: any way to fix?

Tags: laptop, display, connector, hp-envy, hp-laptop

For the past few months the right ~1/3 of my laptop (HP Envy 15-u011dx) screen is either black or has a bunch of colored vertical stripes on it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFTKV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZb1U.jpg

I've traced the issue to the connector on the back of the LCD display panel where the display ribbon cable from the motherboard connects:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoCBO.jpg

When I press on the connector, I can get the right side of the display to work again, but only for as long as I can hold it down. I tried taping the connection down with electrical tape to keep the pressure on it, but it only worked for about and hour and a half.

Is there any way to fix this without spending ~$60-70 on a whole new display? I was thinking maybe I could reflow the solder on the connector using a hair dryer or something, but that could be risky.

Comment: It's really unlikely the socket is bad. It could be the cable or it is the screen itself. I can't say I've ever seen the socket go bad. But, I have had to disconnect, clean with contact cleaner and reconnect before.  You have to be really specific with your testing. Any pushing you are doing is flexing the entire board and screen. This is either the cable or screen and based on your comments Id say the screen. No it can't be reflowed. The connection that is bad isn't even soldered.

Comment: I thought it was the cable so I bought a new one, but it didn't solve the issue, so I was sure it was the connector. I'll try cleaning with contact cleaner or rubbing alcohol I guess.

Comment: That back area of the screen is extremely sensitive. Any little movement could be all it takes to get a reaction and you'd think it was the connector.

Comment: It used to be easily fixed by moving the screen back and forth, but not anymore.

Comment: The fact the problem is getting worse tells me it’s the display